# I'm updating a nested array and it updates the wrong element

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a list of `apiKeys` stored as a nested array of objects below my user. I'm looking to revoke the key using an update query, however, the query is updating the wrong record (seems to be the first `isActive:true` array element).

```js
db.users.update({
          $and: [
            { _id: <TheUserId> },
            { 'apiKeys._id': <TheKeyId> },
            { 'apiKeys.isActive': true } // This means the revoked date can't be changed
          ] 
        },
        {
          $set: {
            'apiKeys.$.isActive': false,
            'apiKeys.$.revokedAt': new Date()
          }
        })
```

<strike>Strangely, it seems to work fine if I remove the `{ _id: <TheUserId> }` (though this could be a false impression on my part).</strike>

Edit: I was incorrect about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is wrong, both properties will search its own condition in any of the object, it will not rely on second property's condition, We need to specify that both properties should be in same object,

```
  { 'apiKeys._id': <TheKeyId> },
  { 'apiKeys.isActive': true }
```

We need to specify that both fields should be in same object using [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/),

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: <TheUserId>,
  apiKeys: {
    $elemMatch: {
      _id: <TheKeyId>,
      isActive: true
    }
  }
},
{
  $set: {
    "apiKeys.$.isActive": false,
    "apiKeys.$.revokedAt": new Date()
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/baYrlAKsuFp)

Comment: I knew it would be something like that, but I don't use the specialist operators in MongoDB enough